# React BootstrapTable how to set row count per page?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react `react-bootstrap-table`. The default count of row is 10 per page. I want to change it to 5. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-bootstrap-table has this follow attributes to change the limit per page.

```
sizePerPageList: [20, 50, 100],
onSizePerPageList: this.onSizePerPageList.bind(this), //number of items to be displayed
onPageChange: this.onPageChange.bind(this), //pagination tours
```

you can use  bind a function on `onSizePerPageList` to  change the state variable that holds your limit.